# Musical diagrams with TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate the following diagram of the Pythagorean Comma with TiKz, but I am not sure where to get started (just the circle part, not necessarily the legends). Any ideas on how I could do this?

[image]

Comment: I understand the problem of pythagorean comma, but I don't understand the diagram. What's the relation between the radius and angles. Can you explain it?

Comment: It's about how you temper an instrument to make believe that 12 perfect fifths equal 7 octaves. There's a very narrow (but audible) difference. The diagram shows that adding the twelve perfect fifths doesn't fit exactly into seven octaves (if the instrument is not tempered). Sort of.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here is a starting point in `tikz` which recreates the diagram in *look only*, the angles aren't accurate. The filling in of the red sector is quite manual, and the thick black line is hiding the fact that the edges aren't actually circular arcs.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i/\l in {0/C, 1/G, 2/D, 3/A, 4/E, 5/BC\(^\flat\), 6/G\(^\flat\)F, 7/D\(^\flat\), 8/A\(^\flat\), 9/E\(^\flat\), 10/B\(^\flat\), 11/F, 12/C} {
            \coordinate (\i) at ({-360*(1/11.5)*\i+90}:2+\i/20);
            \ifnum \i=0
                \node[left] at ({-360*(1/11.5)*\i+90}:2+\i/20) {\l};
            \else
                \node at ({-360*(1/11.5)*\i+90}:2.2+\i/20) {\l};
            \fi
            \draw[lightgray] (0, 0) -- (\i);
            \ifnum \i<12
                \draw[very thick] ({-360*(1/11.5)*\i+90}:2+\i/20) to[bend left=12] ({-360*(1/11.5)*(\i+1)+90}:{2+(\i+1)/20});
            \fi
        }
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \fill[red] (0, 0) -- ($(0) + (0, 0.58)$) arc(90:74.5:2.57) (12) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```